# What methods can be used to cook Skipjack tuna other than frying it in oil?

Tags: fish, budget-cooking

First of all I must say that I'm not a fish person but a red meat person. However I'm currently on a diet and as such I've been looking for different ways to properly cook Tuna with low fat.

I know there are my recipes out there, I'm not looking for an specific one but rather a short summary of the methods used to cook fish without requiring much expertise and can be done quick and without much equipment. Therefore is there anyone who can help me with this?

Please don't say just boiling it in water or putting in the oven for who knows how long. I must add that I do not have access to an oven so the suggestion which would help me the most is one which does refrain from using it.

Maybe this can work but is not what I'm looking for. I'm aiming at something which has proved over the time to be easy to do and use little or almost no oil.

Comment: Roasting/baking is one of the simplest and leanest ways of cooking fish... can you explain why this isn't an option? Why isn't it what you're looking for?

Comment: @Catija Well I do not have an oven that I can use. Also the temperature involved in baking wouldn't it tarnish or deplete the healthy aspects of the fish?.

Comment: Well, saying that you don't have access to an oven is an important caveat for your question, so I suggest you [edit] that in. As to the "health" aspects, this site specifically doesn't get into that but you can absolutely bake at lower temperatures... most ovens can be set as low as 200 F, if not lower. Plus, this type of fish is often served pretty rare, the way beef is (if that's your preference).

Comment: @Catija Alright changed that, but again my major concern about baking is that due the nature of the fish or maybe any meat is that during baking there is a risk of carbonization. Even if the temperature is set to the range you indicated I am having the impresion of could or would happen this, therefore Is there any other way to avoid the protein becomes crunchy in texture or feeling?

Comment: Unless you extremely overcook fish at 200F to the point that it dries out and becomes black... you're not going to carbonize it.. There's also methods like foil pack cooking that keep moist air around the fish, essentially steaming it... but if you don't have an oven or a toaster oven, it's immaterial.

Comment: Choosing a "better" method is completely subjective, so nobody can really give you a method which is best for you, we would be limited to listing different methods from which you would have to choose one. And we don't do big-list questions here. You might want to just search the Internet for "tuna recipes" or similar, or search some recipe database by ingredient, and see what you like.

Comment: @rumtscho I recently edited this question, I do hope that at the way it is now it complies with what this site is for.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell thank you for editing, I have reopened.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

- Raw. If your fish is great quality and very fresh, and you have  a good sharp knife (just look up the way to cut it for the nicest texture)
- Ceviche. This cooks (denatures) the fish with acid, rather than heat. Lots of recipes out there for great marinades, some with no added oil at all.
- Seared. You only need to add rub enough oil into the surface of the fish to prevent it from sticking, to a hot griddle or flat pan.
- Steamed. Often with aromatics. In a bowl to catch the juices, or wrapped in a loose but well-sealed package of foil or greaseproof paper (*en papillote*).

Gently poached in good oil is very nice, but I don't think that would meet your dietary requirements!

*En papillote* Is often done in quite a hot oven: the package enforces steaming inside; the fish isn't exposed to fierce heat.

All of these methods will be enhanced by your choice of recipe for dipping sauces, dressings, marinades,  sides, etc. There's no difficult technique in most of them. The lucky thing about good fish is.. the less you do to it, the better it is. (Almost). Look up the methods, and you'll find the recipes.

The only real danger is overcooking. You'll have to get to know your preferred doneness.

Comment: I'd think I'd pass on raw. I know the fish can be eaten raw but is not for me. I think seared is the way to go but it seems to dissuade me a bit the fact that it needs touches of oil. Steamed probably is the best choice but it doesn't mention on how this is made, perhaps a link with a video would help.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell You're on the internet... I assure you "steamed tuna recipe" will give you thousands of results. We're not a recipe sharing site.

Comment: @Catija I was aware about that. Therefore I tried to make a question without being specific into that but rather on methods. However what my goal was to know what should I take consideration to avoid overcooking.